# pandas count values for last 7 days from each date

Tags: python, pandas

There are two `pd.DataFrame`. First is like this:

```
print df1

        id        date    month  is_buy
     0  17  2015-01-16  2015-01       1
     1  17  2015-01-26  2015-01       1
     2  17  2015-01-27  2015-01       1
     3  17  2015-02-11  2015-02       1
     4  17  2015-03-14  2015-03       1
     5  18  2015-01-28  2015-01       1
     6  18  2015-02-12  2015-02       1
     7  18  2015-02-25  2015-02       1
     8  18  2015-03-04  2015-03       1
```

In second data frame there are some aggregated data by month from the first one:

```
df2 = df1[df1['is_buy'] == 1].groupby(['id', 'month']).agg({'is_buy': np.sum})
     
print df2

        id    month       buys
     0  17  2015-01          3
     1  17  2015-02          1
     2  17  2015-03          1
     3  18  2015-01          1
     4  18  2015-02          2
     5  18  2015-03          1
```

I'm trying to get new `df2` column named `'last_week_buys'` with aggregated buys by last 7 days from first day of each `df1['month']`. In other words, I want to get this:

```
        id    month       buys    last_week_buys
     0  17  2015-01          3               NaN
     1  17  2015-02          1                 2
     2  17  2015-03          1                 0
     3  18  2015-01          1               NaN
     4  18  2015-02          2                 1
     5  18  2015-03          1                 1
```

Are there any ideas to get this column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main obstacle is figuring out whether a date is within the last 7 days of the month. I'd recommend something hacky like the following:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
def last7(datestr):
    orig = datetime.strptime(datestr,'%Y-%m-%d')
    plus7 = orig+timedelta(7)
    return plus7.month != orig.month
```

Once you have that, it's relatively simple to adapt your previous code:

```
df3 = df1[df1['is_buy'] == 1 && last7(df1['date'])].groupby(['id', 'month']).agg({'is_buy': np.sum})
```

Now we just join together `df2` and `df3` and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this:

```
patterns = df [['Total','Date']]
patterns = purchase_patterns.set_index("Date")
resample = patterns.resample ('D' , how = sum)

#to extract the last items of the list

last_7 = resample[-7:]

# and to get the total
last_7 = resample[-7:].sum()
```

A reference for data slicing is [here](http://chris.friedline.net/2015-12-15-rutgers/lessons/python2/02-index-slice-subset.html).